# Values Not displaying in graph when using plotly candlestick graphs

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to Graph some values from an excel file. I cannot change anything on the excel. I used .getgroup() with multiple columns to get main values from each month, and then put them into a list which I used to be displayed in a Candlestick graph. I get no errors whatsoever, but apart from the x values, no other data is displayed on the graph.
[image: xlsx Used]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def main():

    df = pd.read_excel('DatosUnited.xlsx')
    
##Formato Mean: mean/mes/año/Columna
##OPEN

    monthYear = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])
    
    june2019 = monthYear.get_group((6, 2019))
    june2019Open = june2019['Open']
    
    mJUN19O = june2019.mean()
    

    july2019 = monthYear.get_group((7, 2019))
    july2019Open = july2019['Open']
    
    mJUL19O = july2019.mean()
    
    aug2019 = monthYear.get_group((8, 2019))
    aug2019Open = aug2019['Open']
    
    mAUG19O = aug2019.mean()
    
    sep2019 = monthYear.get_group((9, 2019))
    sep2019Open = aug2019['Open']   
    
    mSEP19O = sep2019.mean()

    oct2019 = monthYear.get_group((10, 2019))
    oct2019Open = oct2019['Open']
    
    mOCT19O = sep2019.mean()
    
    nov2019 = monthYear.get_group((11, 2019))
    nov2019Open = nov2019['Open']
    
    mNOV19O = nov2019.mean()

    dic2019 = monthYear.get_group((12, 2019))
    nov2019Open = nov2019['Open']
    
    mDIC19O = dic2019.mean()   
   
##High
    
    june2019 = monthYear.get_group((6, 2019))
    june2019High = june2019['High']
    
    mJUN19H = june2019.mean()
    

    july2019 = monthYear.get_group((7, 2019))
    july2019High = july2019['High']
    
    mJUL19H = july2019.mean()
    
    aug2019 = monthYear.get_group((8, 2019))
    aug2019High = aug2019['High']
    
    mAUG19H = aug2019.mean()
    
    sep2019 = monthYear.get_group((9, 2019))
    sep2019High = aug2019['High']   
    
    mSEP19H = sep2019.mean()

    oct2019 = monthYear.get_group((10, 2019))
    oct2019High = oct2019['High']
    
    mOCT19H = sep2019.mean()
    
    nov2019 = monthYear.get_group((11, 2019))
    nov2019High = nov2019['High']
    
    mNOV19H = nov2019.mean()

    dic2019 = monthYear.get_group((12, 2019))
    nov2019High = nov2019['High']
    
    mDIC19H = dic2019.mean()
    
##LOW

    june2019 = monthYear.get_group((6, 2019))
    june2019Low = june2019['Low']
    
    mJUN19L = june2019.mean()
    

    july2019 = monthYear.get_group((7, 2019))
    july2019Low = july2019['Low']
    
    mJUL19L = july2019.mean()
    
    aug2019 = monthYear.get_group((8, 2019))
    aug2019Low = aug2019['High']
    
    mAUG19L = aug2019.mean()
    
    sep2019 = monthYear.get_group((9, 2019))
    sep2019Low = aug2019['Low']   
    
    mSEP19L = sep2019.mean()

    oct2019 = monthYear.get_group((10, 2019))
    oct2019Low = oct2019['Low']
    
    mOCT19L = sep2019.mean()
    
    nov2019 = monthYear.get_group((11, 2019))
    nov2019Low = nov2019['Low']
    
    mNOV19L = nov2019.mean()

    dic2019 = monthYear.get_group((12, 2019))
    nov2019Low = nov2019['Low']
    
    mDIC19L = dic2019.mean()
    
##Close/Price
    

    june2019 = monthYear.get_group((6, 2019))
    june2019C = june2019['Close/Price']
    
    mJUN19c = june2019.mean()
    

    july2019 = monthYear.get_group((7, 2019))
    july2019Low = july2019['Close/Price']
    
    mJUL19c = july2019.mean()
    
    aug2019 = monthYear.get_group((8, 2019))
    aug2019C = aug2019['Close/Price']
    
    mAUG19c = aug2019.mean()
    
    sep2019 = monthYear.get_group((9, 2019))
    sep2019C = aug2019['Close/Price']   
    
    mSEP19c = sep2019.mean()

    oct2019 = monthYear.get_group((10, 2019))
    oct2019Low = oct2019['Close/Price']
    
    mOCT19c = sep2019.mean()
    
    nov2019 = monthYear.get_group((11, 2019))
    nov2019C = nov2019['Close/Price']
    
    mNOV19c = nov2019.mean()

    dic2019 = monthYear.get_group((12, 2019))
    nov2019C = nov2019['Close/Price']
    
    mDIC19c = dic2019.mean()  
    
    
    
    

    
    

    openMeans = [mJUN19O, mJUL19O, mAUG19O, mSEP19O, mOCT19O, mNOV19O, mDIC19O]

    highMeans = [mJUN19H, mJUL19H, mAUG19H, mSEP19H, mOCT19H, mNOV19H, mDIC19H]

    lowMeans = [mJUN19L, mJUL19L, mAUG19L, mSEP19L, mOCT19L, mNOV19L, mDIC19L]

    closeMeans = [mJUN19c, mJUL19c, mAUG19c, mSEP19c, mOCT19c, mNOV19c, mDIC19c]

    dates = ['6-2019', '7-2019','8-2019','9-2019','10-2019','11-2019','12-2019']

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x= dates,
                    open = openMeans,
                    high = highMeans,
                    low= lowMeans,
                    close = closeMeans)])

    fig.show()


main()
```

I believe there is something wrong regarding the format in which the mean values are stored, but I can´t seem to find the solution

Comment: Pasting data to an image is not recommended. Please paste the data as text.

Comment: The candlestick value is the reason for the list of lists: do you want to draw a candlestick with a 7-month average or a 7-month subplot?

Comment: Try this: `df_mean = df.groupby(['Year','Month'])[['Open','High','Low','Close']].mean().reset_index()`